# Pandas filter by more than one "contains" for not one cell but entire column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes, and I want to find the dataframes that contains both the words i specify. For example, I want to find all dataframes that contain the words `hello` and `world`. A & B would qualify, C would not.

I've tried: 
`df[(df[column].str.contains('hello')) & (df[column].str.contains('world'))]` which only picks up B and `df[(df[column].str.contains('hello')) | (df[column].str.contains('world'))]` which picks up all three.

I need something that picks only A & B

A=

```
    Name    Data   
0   Mike    hello    
1   Mike    world    
2   Mike    hello   
3   Fred    world
4   Fred    hello
5   Ted     world
```

B =

```
    Name    Data   
0   Mike    helloworld
1   Mike    world    
2   Mike    hello   
3   Fred    world
4   Fred    hello
5   Ted     world
```

C=

```
    Name    Data   
0   Mike    hello
1   Mike    hello    
2   Mike    hello   
3   Fred    hello
4   Fred    hello
5   Ted     hello
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a single bool value for if `'hello'` is found anywhere and `'world'` is found anywhere in one column:

```
df.Data.str.contains('hello').any() & df.Data.str.contains('world').any()
```

If you have a list of words and need to check over the entire `DataFrame` try:

```
import numpy as np

lst = ['hello', 'world']
np.logical_and.reduce([any(word in x for x in df.values.ravel()) for word in lst])
```

---

#### Sample Data

```
print(df)
   Name   Data   Data2
0  Mike  hello  orange
1  Mike  world  banana
2  Mike  hello  banana
3  Fred  world  apples
4  Fred  hello   mango
5   Ted  world    pear

lst = ['apple', 'hello', 'world']
np.logical_and.reduce([any(word in x for x in df.values.ravel()) for word in lst])
#True

lst = ['apple', 'hello', 'world', 'bear']
np.logical_and.reduce([any(word in x for x in df.values.ravel()) for word in lst])
# False
```

Comment: i notice that you need to go column by column. Is there a `df.str.contains('xxx').any()` type function that applies to the entire `df`? right now I'm looping through columns.

Comment: @jason See my update, though you will need to ensure everything is a string beforehand, which you can do with `.astype`

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
import re 

bool(re.search(r'^(?=.*hello)(?=.*world)', df.sum().sum())
Out[461]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

If hello and world are standalone strings in your data, df.eq() should do the job and you don't need str.contains. Its not a string method and works on entire dataframe.

```
(((df == 'hello').any()) & ((df == 'world').any())).any()

True
```